# How to make Tor work using mobile data?

Tags: orbot, android, mobile, orweb

I have Orbot and Orweb downloaded on my android (samsung s3) it connects when I have my wifi on and I can search fine but when I use my data, the page only loads 25% and then hangs.  Do I need to configure something?  It's been a while since I downloaded this so I thought maybe I restricted Orbot to only use a wifi connection (if that's even possible?) but wouldn't know how to undo it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The setup should be exactly the same, unless your mobile carrier blocks Tor. If that's the case, try using bridges. If Orbot is restricted on mobile data, check your data settings. Also, you should use Orfox instead of Orweb.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to Tor on mobile data the same way you do on WiFi.
In case your Carrier blocks Tor, you could use the bridges available in Orbot.

Answer (score 1):

Root your phone, use OpenVPN, bridges, and test your traffic by disabling Wifi obviously.

You want to run a VPN layered with TOR regardless of the device or the data source.  And you need to root most droids to get all traffic from your phone (apps, not just browser) to pass through TOR.

Comment: You don't always want to run a VPN and you don't need root with the new feature to setup Orbot as an Android VPN provider.