# How do I set up tor on my android galaxy s9?

Tags: orbot, android

I'm new to this, and I've been trying to figure out how to configure orbot and the tor browser. I either get no connectivity or just a few Kbps. I don't know the optimal settings for speed and privacy. I also am curious if I'll have to root my phone to use it and the best way to do that if so. I also need advice on the best sites on the dark web.

> the question is duplicate, you can find your answer here [How to use bridges in Orbot?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/how-to-use-bridges-in-orbot/20238#20238)

Answer (score 1):

First of all.  This is not the [DARK WEB]. 
Simply it's taking back you privacy and keeping your anatomy safe.  Just like you I also didn't know much about TOR. 
So first step is to apps that may infringe on your privacy. Mostly GOOGLE apps.  Go thru all your apps [PERMISSIONS] Settings! And SEE how much of your privacy you're giving up!